# I tried making a form of dynamic nature in django which change the number of fields in template as per user. screenshot of which is given below

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

[image]

I'm planning to make a dynamic forms in `django` which takes 3 basic fields one char type, one date type and one numeric integer value. I use basic `django model` forms and render method to save the form in database. But I'm unable to perform that operation in this dynamic form.
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the relevant code (which is probably the form class, the model, the view and perhaps the template too), and describe in more detail what isn't working.

Comment: So you want to show fields one by one right ?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari yes

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in jquery/javascript in django template

Render simple form with all fields first see what are name of components `id` or `name`

then you show the first field and hide the other two on pageload

```
$("#idofcomponent2").hide()
$("#idofcomponent3").hide()

$("#idofcomponent1").on("focusout",function(){
//show second component here and hide the first
  $(this).hide();
$("#idofcomponent2").show()
});


$("#idofcomponent2").on("focusout",function(){
//show second component here and hide the first
  $(this).hide();
$("#idofcomponent3").show()
});
```

I was not able to test it. Please let me know.